# UsingMicrosoft Graph api in C# how to get the list of currently logged in user(Active session) in my application using azure Ad authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-web-api2, azure-ad-graph-api

We are using azure ad for authentication for our application and dealing with token expiration of Azure Ad. 
We need to fetch the list of users who are currently working (logged in ) into the application. 
And the list of users signed out(logged off) from the  application.

Its like to track the online and offline users on our application. 
which Microsoft graph API we need to use . I went thru the Microsoft documentation but couldn't find the API for this use case. 
Please share some code or the way I can achieve without storing user session in my db.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to tell you there is no such graph api command as far as I'm aware. like you said the only way to reliably do it is storing user session information on your own.

the only other thing that I can think of that you could do is try to extrapolate login information from azure audit logs, get get an approximation. you can get a list of sign-ins as per this graph endpoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

There is also the endpoint auditLogs/directoryAudits  as per here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/view-audit-logs 
that may show some information about the id tokens being issued.

other than those 2 options, I don't believe there is any better way at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @alphaz18 I have raised concern with Azure team as well. If they don't provide any solution, I will go with manual storing the user session information.

Answer (score 0):

After discussion with Microsoft team, We get the input that they don't have any graph api to fetch the active /logged in user list on hosted  application.

But we can trace the audit logs api which will help us to get the list of users logged in at certain time. But  that list is also not a real time it may have delay of 5 to 10 minutes. 
We are going with manually handle the user session details.

pasting below audit log api for reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http